# On click the template data needs to be rendered in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-helper

I am trying to render the data(from the template) like hide(when back button is clicked) and show(when the view button is clicked) on the same HTML page. My code is below:

```
<h2>Saved Deals</h2>
<p>This includes deals which are in draft</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-black fjalla" id="viewsaveddeals" role="button">View »</a>{{> saveddeals}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Meteor [`Sessions`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session), for example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.deals.helpers({
        showSavedDeals: function () {
            return Session.equals('showSavedDeals', true);
        }
    });
    Template.deals.events({
        'click #viewsaveddeals': function () {
            Session.set('showSavedDeals', true);
        }
    });
    Template.deals.onDestroyed(function () {
        Session.set('showSavedDeals', null);
    });
}
```

---

```
<template name="deals">
    <h2>Deals<span>12</span></h2>

    <p>This includes deals which are in draft</p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-black fjalla" id="viewsaveddeals" role="button">View
        »</a>{{#if showSavedDeals}}{{> saveddeals}}{{/if}}</p>
</template>

<template name="saveddeals">
    <h2>Saved deals</h2>
</template>
```